# Change YYYY-MM-DD to YYYYMMDD everywhere in file

Tags: vim, find-and-replace

I can't just delete all of the hyphens, because elsewhere they are used as minus signs. I can find these dates with `[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}` but I can't figure out how to keep those three different digit wildcards in memory. My attempts end up replacing the dates with the search string (e.g., `:%s/[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}/[0-9]\{4\}[0-9]\{2\}[0-9]\{2\}/g`).

Any ideas? If there's a command line solution, I'd love to learn that, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use capture groups:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1\2\3/g
```

The parentheses capture the matches within, then the backreferences output those capture groups. Since the hyphens are outside the groups, they're excluded.

Comment: You can also simplify `[0-9]` with `\d`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know vim so this is a workaround that you can still perform in vim:

Since you can find the hyphens that occur in dates, replace them with something else (a character or sttring) that you know doesn't occur in the document. Then do a second search/replace to replace your new character/string with nothing, thereby deleting it.

Comment: but wouldn't that delete the minus signs I need elsewhere?